# Unable to fix: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, maven, java-home

I am taking a spring boot course and am up to a stage where the program is being run from the command window. I thought I had downloaded maven correctly but if I type `mvn package` I get:

`'mvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`mvnw package`:
`JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.`

`mvnw -version` gives the same message as above and `mvn -version` gives:
`The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program.`

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` path as shown in the screenshot but it is still not working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFvWn.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk3RF.png

When I type echo `%JAVA_HOME%` into cmd I get:
`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe`

and when I change the `JAVA_HOME` path to that I get the same result.

I have added the path extensions as shown in the image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZfUj.png

If anyone can help that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` should have the absolute path to the java installation, most probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java` in the given case.

Comment: When I change JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` I get the same result

Comment: You should set it to the **directory** of the Java installation, not to an executable like `java.exe`. The suggestion by Turing85 is wrong, because `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java` is not a Java installation, it is only a collection of files which will look up the "current" Java installation themselves using the registry (and only for Oracle Java).

Comment: In other words, find out where your Java is really installed, and set it to that **directory**. For example, I use Eclipse Adoptium, so the correct directory is `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.6.10-hotspot`. I believe Oracle installs into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-<version>`, but it has been a few years since I used an Oracle Java installer, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your input. I have set my directory to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5`, which I believe is what you're saying but I'm getting the same result. 
`Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.`
Is there a reason the `JAVA_HOME` isn't changing when I change the directory in my environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, so if future people come into the same problem as me I had to delete

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`

From the `Path` and have no Java-related entries in the `User variables`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu 22 setup from terminal.

This setup for java 8. Same setup command for higher version.

Setup `$JAVA_HOME` Environment:

Step 1 :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Step 2 :

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

**OR :**

Step 1 :

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Step 2 :

Paste  this line on nano text editor

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

To save this press `ctrl+O` and then press `ctrl+X`

Step 3 :

```
source /etc/environment
```

Step 4 :

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for windows?